# How can I test if a remote server is up in Linux?

Tags: linux, shell

I want to test that my remote databases are up by testing connectivity to the DB port.
Is there a simple way to do this in a linux shell script?
My servers running on hosts X1, X2, ..., Xn and y on port P1, P2, ..., Pn
I want to query all of them from admin server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

there are many possibilities how to achieve this, but I think most relaible way to do this is use NAGIOS plugin nrpe_tcp.

Please check:

http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/*-TCP-and-UDP-%28Generic%29

Comment: Is there a way to do this without installing new software like nagios, simply using shell commands?

Comment: Hi, the program is actualy shell script which utilize netstat grep and sed.Please read it first ;) Download link is here : http://exchange.nagios.org/components/com_mtree/attachment.php?link_id=1682&cf_id=24

Comment: As far as I understand this check only on the local server the script is running on. I want to check remote servers from a single location.
Say I have local server S and remote server R1,...Rn. I want to test all remote servers from a single script running on S.

Comment: My excuse, please use this one : "http://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/*-TCP-and-UDP-%28Generic%29/check_port-2Epl/details". Please copy link between "

Answer (score 0):

You can use telnet to check if ports are ready for connection.

Comment: Or netcat, which is less awkward to script.

Comment: netcat needs to be installed, I am looking for an out-of-the-box solution

Answer (score 0):

You may either use netcat directly or more our test tool dda-serverspec for more dedicated tests (https://github.com/DomainDrivenArchitecture/dda-serverspec-crate) for such tasks. You may define your expectation

```
{:netcat [{:host "mywebserver.com" :port "443"}
          {:host "telnet mywebserver.com" :port "80"}
          {:host "telnet mywebserver.com" :port "8443"}]}
```

and test these expectation either against localhost or against remote hosts (connect by ssh). For remote tests you've to define a targets:

```
{:existing [{:node-name "test-vm1"
             :node-ip "35.157.19.218"}
            {:node-name "test-vm2"
             :node-ip "18.194.113.138"}]
 :provisioning-user {:login "ubuntu"}}
```

You may run the test with `java -jar dda-serverspec.jar --targets targets.edn serverspec.edn`